# R shiny how to partly change dataframe to plot?

Tags: r, shiny

The composition of my data has 4 parts, `all_data <- rbind(data1,data2,data3,data4)` 
In shiny,I want to when I slider sliderinput 1,only data1 changed in this dataframe.
When I change slider 2,only data2 changed in this dataframe.

[image]

But when I changed every slider,all data will change ,maybe I should use `observeEvent`  like this,but I am faild.

```
  observeEvent(ignoreInit = TRUE,
               c(input$Mean1,input$SD1), {
    
    mean1 <- input$Mea1
    sd1 <- input$SD1
    n_sample <- 5
    x1 <- 1:5
    y1 <- rnorm(n_sample,mean1, sd1)
    z1 <-  rep("Distribution 1",length(x1) )
    mean_1 <- rep(mean(y1),length(x1))
    data1 <-data.frame(x = x1,y = y1,z = z1,my_mean =mean_1)
  })
```

There is all my code, could you please tell me how to modify it. Thanks!

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)  
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)



ui_chart <- sidebarPanel(width =3,position = "right",
                         sliderInput("Mean1", "Mean of the distrubution1", -30, 30, value = -10),
                         sliderInput("Mean2", "Mean of the distrubution2", -30, 30, value = 0),
                         sliderInput("Mean3", "Mean of the distrubution3", -30, 30, value = 10),
                         sliderInput("Mean4", "Mean of the distrubution4", -30, 30, value = 20),
                         sliderInput("SD1", "Within group sd", 0.1, 20, value =6)
)

ui <- navbarPage("Distrubution for each group", theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                 tabPanel("Distrubution simulation",
                          titlePanel("Within group and between group variance"),
                          mainPanel(width = 9
                                    ,plotlyOutput("chart2")
                          )
                          ,ui_chart
                 )
    
)


server <- function(input, output) {
 
  output$chart2 <- renderPlotly({

    mean1 <- input$Mean1
    mean2 <- input$Mean2
    mean3 <- input$Mean3
    mean4 <- input$Mean4
    sd1 <- input$SD1
    n_sample <- 5
    
    x1 <- 1:5
    y1 <- rnorm(n_sample,mean1, sd1)
    z1 <-  rep("Distribution 1",length(x1) )
    mean_1 <- rep(mean(y1),length(x1))
    data1 <-data.frame(x = x1,y = y1,z = z1,my_mean =mean_1 )
    
    x2 <- 6:10
    y2 <- rnorm(n_sample,mean2, sd1)
    z2 <-  rep("Distribution 2",length(x2) )
    mean_2 <- rep(mean(y2),length(x2))
    data2 <-data.frame(x = x2,y = y2,z = z2,my_mean =mean_2)
    
    x3 <- 11:15
    y3 <- rnorm(n_sample,mean3, sd1)
    z3 <-  rep("Distribution 3",length(x3) )
    mean_3 <- rep(mean(y3),length(x3))
    data3 <-data.frame(x = x3,y = y3,z = z3,my_mean =mean_3)
    
    x4 <- 16:20
    y4 <- rnorm(n_sample,mean4, sd1)
    z4 <-  rep("Distribution 4",length(x4) )
    mean_4 <- rep(mean(y4),length(x4))
    data4 <-data.frame(x = x4,y = y4,z = z4,my_mean =mean_4)
    
    
    all_data <- rbind(data1,data2,data3,data4)
    all_data$mean_all <- mean(all_data$y)
    
    p2 <- ggplot(data = all_data)+
      geom_point(aes(x = x ,y = y,color = z))+
      geom_line(aes(x = x ,y = my_mean  ,color = z))+
      geom_line(aes(x = x ,y = mean_all  ),color = "black")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:20),
                         labels =  paste0("Obs",1:20))+
      ggtitle("Observed sampale data")+
      theme_bw()+
      labs(color = "Distribution")+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    
    ggplotly(p2)
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are using `rnorm`, you are getting new random values every-time an input changes. If you want to isolate those changes, you might want to make separate reactive data objects for each of the studies. Here's one way to do that

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  generate_data <- function(dist, ids, n_sample, sample_mean, sample_sd) {
    x <- 1:5
    y <- rnorm(n_sample,sample_mean, sample_sd)
    z <-  rep(paste("Distribution", dist),length(x) )
    mean <- rep(mean(y),length(x))
    data.frame(x = ids, y = y, z = z, my_mean =mean)
  }
  
  n_sample <- 5
  
  data1 <- reactive(generate_data("1", 1:5, n_sample, input$Mean1, input$SD1))
  data2 <- reactive(generate_data("2", 6:10, n_sample, input$Mean2, input$SD1))
  data3 <- reactive(generate_data("3", 11:15, n_sample, input$Mean3, input$SD1))
  data4 <- reactive(generate_data("4", 16:20, n_sample, input$Mean4, input$SD1))
  
    
  output$chart2 <- renderPlotly({
    
    all_data <- rbind(data1(),data2(),data3(),data4())
    all_data$mean_all <- mean(all_data$y)
    
    p2 <- ggplot(data = all_data)+
      geom_point(aes(x = x ,y = y,color = z))+
      geom_line(aes(x = x ,y = my_mean  ,color = z))+
      geom_line(aes(x = x ,y = mean_all  ),color = "black")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:20),
                         labels =  paste0("Obs",1:20))+
      ggtitle("Observed sampale data")+
      theme_bw()+
      labs(color = "Distribution")+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    
    ggplotly(p2)
  })
  
  
}
```

Here we make a helper function to generate the data for each of the groups. We store the data in a reactive object that only depends on the group mean. Therefore they won't change when other inputs change